# Creating a circle around a letter inside a H1 tag

Tags: html, css

Creating a circle around a letter or text works fine, but in my case I only want to circle a single letter within a word (which is within an H1 tag):

```css
.large {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: -0.5% 5% 0% 5%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="large">
  <span class="circle">e</span>Text
</h1>
```

Fiddle is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/henzen/zwph2nsv/4/
This produces:

[image]

Notice that the circle is conforming to the H1 height (I think) - I need it to be compressed vertically, ie the vertical padding needs to be the same as the horizontal, tightly wrapped around the "e".

Is this possible, or would I need to separate the "e" from the "Text" completely in the HTML?

I have tried Unicode chars (eg, &#9428), which work, but cannot be reliably styled across browsers.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo element.

```css
    .large {
      font-size: 5em;
    }

   .circle {
     position: relative;
     color: red;
    }
    
    .circle:after {
      content: '';
      width: 39px;
      height: 44px;
      border: 4px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
      left: -5px;
      top: 27px;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="large">
  <span class="circle">e</span>Text
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, problem with that approach is that if I change the H1 size (eg, to `3em`), then the circle is way off, or changing the border thickness also breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

use a pseudo element.

Try This: https://jsfiddle.net/2gtazqdy/12/

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.large {
  font-size: 5em;
}


.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.circle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 4px;

  content: "";

  color: red;

  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

My output:
[image: my output]

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: use a pseudo element.

Comment: my output / result is different compared to @Sun's one below/above, check both out. take the one you like.

Comment: Thanks all - both versions work.  Will need a bit of tweaking depending on sizes etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
for your html do `<h1> <span> C </span> ircle </h1>`

then in the css define your h1 span
and give it padding, in the shape of a rectangle you could use this =

```
padding: 20px 10px;
```

then add a border, for example =

```
border: 5px solid #ddd;
```

then at last give it a border radius, this is a bit tidious to figure out but just play around with the pixels and you'll eventually get it right how you want it.
for example =

```
Border-radius: 20px
```

your html:

```
<h1> <span> C </span>ircle </h1>
```

your total css:

```
h1 span{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 5px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a circle, the following is needed:

- `display: inline-block` (or `display: block`)
- same **width**, **height** and **line-height**
- `text-align: center`

Use **em** to correspond with the **font-size** of the container.

### Example

```css
.large {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0.05em solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="large">
  <span class="circle">e</span>Text
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @sun - that almost works.  The circle needs to be even spacing around the 'e' though.  Bottom of the circle is correct, but the top circle line spacing is off.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Please send me a picture with the desired result. (You can play around with `vertical-align`.)

Answer (score 0):

### Please try this code

```css
.large{
text-align: center;
font: 40px Arial, sans-serif;
color:#000;
font-weight:bold;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
background: #fff;
border: 6px solid red;
padding: 3px 10px;
text-align: center;
font: 28px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="large">
  <span class="circle">e</span>Text
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @Romani, but as mentioned in my original post, the circle needs to be tighter around the 'e'